# DataTable PDF Export orders wrong

Tags: pdf, datatables

My dataTable automatically is ordered by the third column with the setting `order: [2, 'asc']` in the config. This works correctly. In the `buttons` section on the config I added the setting `exportOptions: { modifier: {search: 'none', order: 'original'} }` with the expectation that this would order the exported table by the third column as well. However when I do export the table, it is ordered by the second column instead.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this config with the `csv` button. I assume it will be the same for `pdf`

```js
{
    extend: 'csv',
    className: 'btn btn-info btn-sm',
    exportOptions: {
        filter: 'applied',
        order: 'current'
    }
}
```

According to https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/45560/set-order-for-export-to-excel-pdf you can set the `order` value to `index` if you want the original order

```js
modifier: { order: 'index' }
```

Comment: Putting `order: 'original'` directly into `exportOptions` instead of into `modifier` was the trick! Thank you